# NameError: name 'mainscreen' is not defined in GUI tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

1. File "C:/Users/U/Desktop/GUI/loginpage.py", line 11, in 
   username=StringVar(mainscreen)
   NameError: name 'mainscreen' is not defined
2. I try to change the name of GUI window from mainscreen to root but the 
   same prob arise NameError: name 'root' is not defined

   ```
   from tkinter import*

   username=StringVar(mainscreen)
   pwd=StringVar(mainscreen)

   def login():

       messagebox.showwarning("LogInDetail","username="+username.get(),
       "password="+pwd.get())

       l3=Label(text="Your name="+username.get())
       l3.place(x=10,y=125)

       l4=Label(text="Your password="+pwd.get())
       l4.place(x=10,y=150)

   mainscreen=Tk()
   mainscreen.title("GUI")
   mainscreen.geometry("500x500")
   mainscreen.configure(bg="white")

   l1=Label(text="your name")
   l1.place(x=10,y=10)

   l2=Label(text="your password")
   l2.place(x=10,y=50)

   # here i provide 2 entrybox e1 and e2 
   e1=Entry(mainscreen,textvariable=username)
   e1.place(x=120,y=10)

   e2=Entry(mainscreen,textvariable=pwd,show="*")  
   e2.place(x=120,y=50)

   # here i provide button

   loginbutton=Button(text="Login",bg="lightgreen",fg="black",
   width="15",height="8",command=login)
   loginbutton.place(x=120,y=90)

   mainscreen.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: You're trying to reference `mainscreen` before you've created it.

Comment: Yes , sir you are right before checking any response to my ques , i realized my mistake .Thank you to all you for correction ,it helps me

Answer (score 1):

You did not declare mainscreen before trying to use it.

```py
from tkinter import*

def login():

    messagebox.showwarning("LogInDetail","username="+username.get(),
    "password="+pwd.get())

    l3=Label(text="Your name="+username.get())
    l3.place(x=10,y=125)

    l4=Label(text="Your password="+pwd.get())
    l4.place(x=10,y=150)

mainscreen=Tk()
username=StringVar(mainscreen) # move here
pwd=StringVar(mainscreen) # move here
mainscreen.title("GUI")
mainscreen.geometry("500x500")
mainscreen.configure(bg="white")

l1=Label(text="your name")
l1.place(x=10,y=10)

l2=Label(text="your password")
l2.place(x=10,y=50)

# here i provide 2 entrybox e1 and e2 
e1=Entry(mainscreen,textvariable=username)
e1.place(x=120,y=10)

e2=Entry(mainscreen,textvariable=pwd,show="*")  
e2.place(x=120,y=50)

# here i provide button

loginbutton=Button(text="Login",bg="lightgreen",fg="black",
width="15",height="8",command=login)
loginbutton.place(x=120,y=90)

mainscreen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are initializing `mainscreen` after accessing.